# React hook - Can I use common variable out of function(hook) or Is it anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I recently use react hook well. however sometime I wonder my coding style is okay.

```
let mDown = false;
let timerId = null;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    mDown = true
    ....
  }, [])
}
```

Like bottom code, I declare variable out of function. and I want to use common variable and access, change this value without using state.

Is it anti-pattern?

Thanks to read. :)

Comment: Yup, this is a normal behaviour, not an anti-pattern, unless your UI depends on those 
dynamic values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's think in terms of components. I mean, let's ignore for a while there barely will be more than one `<App />` but think about component-centric approach in general.

Do you mean some data independent for each component's instance? Then you use `useState`(if changing this data should re-render component) or `useRef`(if updating this should never trigger re-rendering).

Or should that data be shared among all the components? Then, again it depends. Sometimes global variable is fine(real global variable, as a property on `window` object), sometimes better to put it into Context API or any state management layer(Mobx, Redux) instead.

Why don't have module-level variable as you aer going to? I see multiple reasons(again, maybe not big deal for exact case with `<App />`):

1. Module-level variable sticks to module instance. If we you ever end with multiple version of the same component in the same application, they will have own instances of such a variable. Think of `<Dropdown />` component and some variable made to collapse all other instances once some is expanded. In case with module-level variable you may end some dropdown closes some instances - but not all - just if you got few versions of the same package used(like coming as 2nd level dependency)
2. No access, and no isolation - hard to unit-test.

And finally: what could be a profit here?

Comment: Thanks! It's good to read. I can use useRef instead of variable.

Answer (score 3):

yes, of course. you can use the common variable in not only the hook function, but also any other methods of the App.

however the best practice is to make the global variables in other js files like constant.js, and import them in the above of the file.

```
import { mDown, timerId } from '../constant'
```

Comment: You mean it is not anti-pattern? :)

Comment: no, it's not. sometimes global variable is necessary for dev.